# Remove all fragments up to particular fragment in stack android

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

Hi I am developing android application in which I am using fragments and push to back stack. So my scenario is like this I have fragment A, B, C, D and I push them in following sequence A-->B-->C-->D and what I want I want to remove D and C and bring B on top. Is there any way to remove all together and bring one particular fragment on top of the stack. like pop from back stack upto xyz fragment tag. Is there any way to do this. Need help thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want this: [`FragmentManager.popBackStack(int id, int flags)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack%28int,%20int%29)

You need to save the value returned by [`FragmentTransaction.commit()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit%28%29) of the transaction that adds Fragment B. Then later call `getFragmentManager().popBackStack(commitId, 0)`;

Comment: Hi Karakuri thank you for quick replay. I checked this method on googles document. But I am able to understand its use properly. can you please explain how it works. Thank you for your are help ...

Comment: Sure. The first argument is an integer ID. `FragmentTransaction.commit()` returns an integer value. This value is the ID you want to use when calling `popBackStack(id, flags)`. Find in your code the transaction that adds Fragment B to your activity and make sure you store the value returned by `commit()`. The second argument is just a flag that tells the FragmentManager whether you want to pop only transactions back to the ID (exclusive), or to pop the ID also (inclusive) which would take you back to Fragment A. Pass zero to specify exclusive.